# SQL query to convert duplicate column values to unique value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need help to come up with an update query to make the value column to be unique values. I use Postgres.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  value INT
);
INSERT INTO test (id,value) VALUES ('1','100');
INSERT INTO test (id,value) VALUES ('2','100');
INSERT INTO test (id,value) VALUES ('3','100');
INSERT INTO test (id,value) VALUES ('4','101');
INSERT INTO test (id,value) VALUES ('5','101');
INSERT INTO test (id,value) VALUES ('6','101');
```

The update should convert the above table to be:

```
id                      value
==                     =======
1                        100
2                        102
3                        103
4                        101
5                        104
6                        105
```

Comment: You need to provide the formula like `new_value = f(old_value)` Without it any answers to this question is the dummy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following update statement will achieve the result you are seeking.

```
update test 
set value = t.newvalue 
from (
with dupnum as (
  select *, 
  row_number() over (partition by value order by id) rn, 
  max(value) over () maxv 
  from test
)
select 
  id
, row_number() over (order by id) + maxv newvalue
from dupnum where rn > 1) t 
where t.id = test.id
```

Comment: The above query almost worked as I wanted, except for duplicates in record with id = 2,4. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cTbH71XQucm2JtehyhAneT/0

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I'm not sure if you have a particular logic in mind, but this does what you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then value
             else max(value) over () + row_number() over (partition by seqnum = 1 order by id)
        end) as new_value
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by value order by id) as seqnum
      from test t
     ) t
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8eeed9521f25655034788c49b520225a) is a db<>fiddle.

I should note that if you don't need to preserve existing values, the simplest method is:

```
select t.*, min(value) over () + row_number() over (order by id) - 1 as new_value
from test t;
```